# R efficient search in data.frame

Tags: r, performance

I want using `R` to organize the most efficient search a value ​​in tables in the format `data.frame` like this

```
    x01 x02 x03 x04 x05 x06 x07
 1  NA 100 200 300 400 500 600
 2  10   1   4   3   6   7   1
 3  20   2   5   2   5   8   2
 4  30   3   6   1   4   9   8
```

Values ​​in the first row and first column in order of increasing. For example, I need to find value to the crosshairs of a column containing `300` in the first row and the row containing `20` in the first column. The value `2`. Code for this:

```
coefficient_table_1 <- data.frame(
 x01=c(NA,  10, 20, 30),
 x02=c(100, 1,  2,  3),
 x03=c(200, 4,  5,  6),
 x04=c(300, 3,  2,  1),
 x05=c(400, 6,  5,  4),
 x06=c(500, 7,  8,  9),
 x07=c(600, 1,  2,  8)
)


col_value <- 300
row_value <- 20

col <- 0

for(i in 2:ncol(coefficient_table_1)){
    if(coefficient_table_1[1,i]==col_value ){
        col <- i
    }
}

row <- which(coefficient_table_1$x01==row_value)


value <- coefficient_table_1[row, col]
```

Table can be large and the search can be arranged inside the loop. What is the most effective way to search in data.frame?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data is all numeric, so your best course of action is probably to use arrays, rather than data frames.

Since arrays contain data of only a single class (e.g. numeric), many operations are much faster when your data is in array format.

Try this:

```
x <- as.matrix(coefficient_table_1)
x[which(x[, 1]==row_value), which(x[1, ]==col_value)]

x04 
  2
```

Comment: Might be worth mentioning the ability to return matrix coordinates, as in `which(my.mat == 7, array.indices=TRUE)`